# Signing up with Zelle with a foreign address

Tags: online-banking

I received $300 from family by Zelle notification in email.
I tried to sign up with Zelle, and my bank is a Zelle member, but the online app refused.
Could it be because my banking address is foreign?
Nothing is mentioned on the Zelle site?

Comment: Have you contacted Zelle? Or your bank?

Comment: And just to be safe: were you _expecting_ to receive this money, and/or can you check with the relative (using a _known_ phone/email address)? If you received "_A relative has sent you $300..._" or similar out-of-the-blue it could be a scam, potentially directing you to a fake registration site where they can grab your details.